# How does the '|' operator work in R?

Tags: r, syntax

I'm trying to understand the `|` operator in R. Why does

```
a = 2
a == 3 | 4
```

return `TRUE` in R?

```
a == 3
```

and

```
a == 4
```

each return `FALSE` so why does the second line return `TRUE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `help(Syntax)` -- the `==` has higher precedence than the `|`.

So:

```
R> a <- 2
R> a == 3 | 4
R> TRUE
R> a == (3 | 4)
R> FALSE
```

Comment: The moral: **always** use a few extra parentheses.  You'll thank yourself someday down the road.

Comment: It's wort pointing out that `a == (3 | 4)` does not test if `a` is equal to 3 or 4. It tests `a == TRUE`, where the logical value is coerced to a numeric value. So, `3 == (3 | 4)` is FALSE, but `1 == (3 | 4)` is TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this:

```
`|`(a == 3, 4)
`==`(a, 3)
as.logical(2) # TRUE
as.logical(3) # TRUE
as.logical(4) # TRUE
```

So, what is happening is that both sides of `a == 3` are coerced to logical; that evaluates to `TRUE == TRUE` which is `TRUE`. After that an `or` operation between `TRUE` and `4` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a == 3 | 4
```

Means:

Is either (a equal to 3) or (4)?

Coincidentally, 4 evaluates to TRUE when coerced to logical.